# how to move files from one server to another server using scp?

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I am trying to move uploaded file to another server using scp. following is the script i am using and error;

"mv.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh
now=$(date +"%y-%m-%d-%M")
    cd /var/www/upload

        if [ -f /var/www/upload/* ];
        then
                    scp -P 88 * user@192.168.2.1:backup/
        STATUS=$?
        echo "$now-S1:succesful." >> /var/log/mv_to.log
        else
            echo "$now-S1:Error!!" >> /var/log/mv_to.log
    fi
```

error;

```
[: 13: /var/www/upload/1.doc: unexpected operator
```

If there is only one file it works fine and if there are two or more files it says unexpected operator. Please correct me here.

Comment: Isn't rsync a better option than scp?  Your script wants to copy every file in the directory.  If you don't  remove files from upload after they've been copied, you'll re-copy them when you run your script next.  Also, rysnc comes with a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your if statement. You can replace it with:

```
    if [ -d /var/www/upload/ ];
```

(instead of checking that a file exists, which gives an error if there's more than one file, it checks that the directory exists)

Comment: But I also need to log if file doesn't exist??

Comment: Unless he plans on creating and deleting the directory over and over, isn't it better that he not include the if statement?

Comment: To check that at least some files exist in the upload directory, use: `if [ "$(ls -A /var/www/upload/)" ];`